Flutter Desktop App: Window Shadow Not Showing on Windows 7
I'm currently developing a desktop application using Flutter, and I've customized the title bar of the window. Everything works as expected on Windows 10, 11, and 8, with shadows appearing appropriately. However, when I launch the application on Windows 7, the window shadow doesn't show up.
I've attempted to enable the shadow programmatically using the window_manager package, but it hasn't resolved the issue. Additionally, I've tried enabling shadow outlines from the Windows settings, but that hasn't worked either.
Could someone please advise on how to ensure that the window shadow appears correctly on Windows 7 while maintaining the custom title bar in Flutter?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
windowManager.setHasShadow(true);

